# Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'firstElementChild')

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, puppeteer

I'm trying to trigger click event but in Ubuntu server it is not working.

```
....
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector(".phone").firstElementChild.click();
  });
 .....
```

[image]

Comment: Can you attach your whole HTML template ?

Comment: There in no templates, it is working in my local server, but in server it doesn't

Comment: Try doing this next thing, `console.log(document.querySelector(".phone"))` and see what you have inside your `NodeList`

Comment: Please show the page DOM you're working with. Where is the `.phone` element?

Comment: I'm doing scrapping, I don't have DOM in my code

Answer (score 0):

Evaluation fails if an element is not present in the DOM ([Document Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)). `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '...')` is the general error in such cases, I can recommend [this StackOverflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) on this topic.

(1) As your script works only locally you need to find the reason what's the difference between the scraped page opened locally vs opened on the server:

- why the element with `.phone` class is not rendered to the DOM?
- are you recognized as a scraper?
- do you get a captcha immediately?
- does the scraped page looks different on the Ubuntu server vs the local computer (rare, but pages can have different content based on User-Agent)?

For this purpose, you can:

1. log the HTML source of the page [(`console.log(await page.content())`)](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=main&show=api-pagecontent)
2. save a screenshot of the page in Base64:

```js
await page.screenshot({ path: __dirname + '/screen.png' })
const screenBase64 = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/screen.png', 'base64')
console.log('data:image/png;base64, ' + screenBase64)
```

You need to find the answer for this yourself and the solution should address this.

---

(2) If your script would throw the same error even locally it would tell that you try to evaluate `.phone` too early before it would be rendered to DOM. This could be handled with awaiting the element:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('.phone')
await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelector('.phone').firstElementChild.click()
})
```